# (Error Dependencias )Missing artifact pentaho-kettle:kettle-engine:jar:4.2.0-stable

Tags: java, maven, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Me da varios errores con las dependencias de pentaho, no tengo ni idea que es lo que pasa, me he copiado el proyecto y todo de un compañero y solo me da ese fallo.

En todos los pom que tengo me da el mismo error, todo en estas líneas:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-stable</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-stable</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-db</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-stable</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-stable</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: El problema es que no tienes acceso a esa dependencia. ¿Tienes configurado el repositorio para bajarla?

Answer (score 0):

Arreglado, mire los jar de las dependencias de maven que tenía instaladas y estaban todas metidas, lo que ha fallado era el Update Project de Maven que no se porque no me los estaba cogiendo, reinicie aplicación lo volví hacer y me lo corrigió.